# Deleting buttons with Id higher than the clicked one

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why my code doesn't work.

I create dynamically groups of three buttons: the first button of the group has id 1, the second 101 and the third 201; buttons of the second group will be named respectively 2, 102 and 202, and so on.

If I want to delete all the three buttons by clicking the last one it works. This is what I set in the onclick event :

```
butt.onclick = function() {
    removeElement(this.id);
    removeElement(this.id-100);
    removeElement(this.id-200);
}
```

But if I want to delete all the three buttons by clicking the middle one with this onclick event:

```
butt.onclick = function() {
    removeElement(this.id+100);
    removeElement(this.id);
    removeElement(this.id-100);
}
```

it eliminates only buttons 1 and 101 but not 201.

It seems like it doesn't like the "this.id+100" value. What's the reason?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get anything in the error console?

Comment: Debug it with firebug in Firefox or equivalent.

Comment: Your mixing string's (`id`) and integer math.  One of many areas javascript will bite back. I'd suggest reading [Javascript - The Good Parts](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CFgQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fshop.oreilly.com%2Fproduct%2F9780596517748.do&ei=A87ET7b6LuTY0QGgr_i3Cg&usg=AFQjCNEixCT-_FFQNTx41rQjj6skDNAHog&sig2=Q8Pd-StoyK_5Bg2NuWY-zw)

Comment: One thing I can think of is that `this.id` resolves to string `101` and then `this.id+100` resolves to string `101100`.  Try this: `removeElement(100+this.id)` (Note that "100" goes first thus indicating that it needs to sum two values as numbers.)

Comment: I'd also point out that you could have figured this out yourself in seconds with any debugger from any browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mixing strings with numbers ... and using the `+` with a string concatenates try

```
butt.onclick = function() {
    removeElement(parseInt(this.id,10)+100);
    removeElement(this.id);
    removeElement(parseInt(this.id,10)-100);
}
```

You use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert strings to numbers in JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Try  `removeElement(parseInt(this.id)+100);`

'+' Operator is used to concatenate, so need to make a number before addition.

Answer (score 0):

In your second snippet, change

```
removeElement(this.id+100);
```

to

```
removeElement(parseInt(this.id)+100);
```